# Changing the value of a hidden field to the value of a checkbox on submit with javascript inside Contact Form 7 Wordpress plugin

Tags: javascript, wordpress, mailchimp

I have been trying to get this working for more than a week now, searching endlessly for the solution and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I am not a coder, just trying to duct tape some functions together to get this working... Please help!

I have the following checkbox inputs on my Contact Form 7 form inside a Wordpress page. I have Mailchimp for Wordpress updating a group which reflects the visitors interests. I'm trying to get the value of the group assigned to a hidden input field so that the built in mail feature and other Zapier integrations can use the interest values. Most of these apps seem to lack support for the groups functionality inside Mailchimp.

The form html is as follows:

```
<p>
    <label>Which Are You Most Interested In?</label></br>
    <label>
        <input name="mc4wp-INTERESTS[gs8o25e9bc][]" type="checkbox" 
value="ac2ed8233d" 
        required=""><span>Interest 1</span>
    </label>
    <label>
        <input name="mc4wp-INTERESTS[gs8o25e9bc][]" type="checkbox" 
value="s3g2c99k0x"
        required=""> <span>Interest 2</span>
    </label>
    <label>
        <input name="mc4wp-INTERESTS[gs8o25e9bc][]" type="checkbox" 
value="k9n6xp3s26"
        required=""> <span>Interest 3</span>
    </label>
</p>

<input type="hidden" id="int-in" name="int-in"</input>
```

--

I've tried several variations of this including some inline stuff, putting the code in the top or bottom of the page, putting it into the Additional section of Contact Form 7, putting it into a scripts plugin inside wordpress, trying to see if it's an array thing and trying code for pushing from array (more over my head) and so many others. Here is what I'm basically trying to do, albeit wrongly via this code because obviously it is not working...

JS:

```
    $('form').submit(function() {
    $('input[name="#mc4wp-INTERESTS[gs8o25e9bc] . 
    []"]').change(function(){ 
    $('#int-in').val($('input[name="#mc4wp-INTERESTS[gs8o25e9bc] . 
    []"]').val());
    });
```

--

Online there is not much support for Mailchimp groups, and I suspect groups functions of most contact apps, not even with paid plugin feature. Mailchimp for Wordpress has the most support I could find and you still have to do some tinkering to get it working. I'm soooo ready to know what the heck works instead of all the stuff I've been trying! Thank you in advance. I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress disables the `$` shortcut, so you need to either replace `$` with `jQuery` or wrap your code:

```
(function($){
  // your code here
})(jQuery);
```

Plus, the `name` of those checkboxes doesn't contain a hashtag. I also have no idea what you're doing with those dots and linebreaks there.
In addition, you're assigning a `onchange` handler only when the form is submitted, but you'll want that to work from the start instead.

Here's a solution that sets the `onchange` handler to grab the value from all checked checkboxes and puts it into the hidden input.

```js
var selector = 'form input[name="mc4wp-INTERESTS[gs8o25e9bc][]"]';

(function($) {
  $(selector).change(function() {
    var interests = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(selector))
      .filter(e => e.checked).map(e => e.value).join(",");
    $('#int-in').val(interests);
    console.log("set to", interests);
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <p>
    <label>Which Are You Most Interested In?</label><br/>
    <label>
        <input name="mc4wp-INTERESTS[gs8o25e9bc][]" type="checkbox" 
value="ac2ed8233d"><span>Interest 1</span>
    </label>
    <label>
        <input name="mc4wp-INTERESTS[gs8o25e9bc][]" type="checkbox" 
value="s3g2c99k0x"> <span>Interest 2</span>
    </label>
    <label>
        <input name="mc4wp-INTERESTS[gs8o25e9bc][]" type="checkbox" 
value="k9n6xp3s26"> <span>Interest 3</span>
    </label>
  </p>

  <input type="hidden" id="int-in" name="int-in">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Not quite true, wordpress does not disable the "$ shortcut". jQuery just needs to be initialised correctly.  i.e.  jQuery(document).ready(function($)
{....});

Comment: The above solution works, thank you. I don't know how those dots/linebreaks got there... I think it was from trying to format the code for this post question lol... I do have another checkbox on the form which is getting added to the value of the interests now though. Is there a way to exclude it from adding that checkbox or specifically select the interests checkbox only? Thank you again! I feel so much relief already just getting closer.

Comment: I figured it out! Thank you so much for helping me!!!   -- (function($) {
  $('form input[name="mc4wp-INTERESTS[gs8o25e9bc][]"]').change(function() {
    var interests = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('form input[name="mc4wp-INTERESTS[gs8o25e9bc][]"]'))
      .filter(e => e.checked).map(e => $(e).next().text()).join(", ");
    $('#int-in').val(interests);
    console.log("set to", interests);
  });
})(jQuery);

Comment: Sorry, erm, seems like the form is buggy now... depending on which box is checked the value will come back blank sometimes. :/ Is that because I changed it to go by name instead of type? Any fix that can correct this?

Comment: @GavinSimpson What I mean is that you can usually start right with `$(...).bla()`, provided the script is below the elements it refers to, and no wrapper is necessary. The one you used is required if the script is in the head and therefore needs to wait until after the DOM is ready, but it basically proves my claim that one cannot use `$` instead of `jQuery` (which I therefore labelled a "shortcut") without a wrapper in a Wordpress environment (because WP uses [this](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/))

Comment: @kcswk I changed it to use your selector, and it seems to work fine, as you can check when you run the snippet in my answer. If it won't work for you, put the entire actual `<form>`s HTML on your question so I can take a look.

Comment: the code you sent is working fine. it seems like the error is actually coming from the javascript validation plugin i installed. now i'm just reading about how there's no out of the box way to validate a required checkbox group without a javascript solution lol and i'm getting tired and overwhelmed again. the code snippets i find online usually don't come with the handy jquery wrapper you put around the code. i did put the js lib in the header... figured that was where it's supposed to go. i'll probably need to start a new thread.

Comment: Agreed Chris G, technically I guess that is true.

Comment: Hi there, is there any reason why the code provided would do this: if you submit the form without the checkbox required fields checked, it will not submit and bounce you back to the checkbox question. Once you then select checkbox items, the first shows up blank and the rest show up fine. The result looks like ", Interest 2, Interest 3" where Interest 1 has been eliminated. I ask because I see in the code the joiner is (", ") and I'm trying to figure out why the first item is being left out in this test.

Comment: @kcswk You set `required` for all three checkboxes; I didn't even pay attention to that or to submitting it, I just copied your form HTML and tested checking and unchecking them.